# Flutter, the last page I closed appears instantly when I open a new page

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

When I switch between pages in the drawer, the previous page appears for 1 second, then it closes and the page I want appears. https://youtube.com/shorts/YS5P2aQLBAM?feature=share

Every time this unwanted page appears, I get this error in the console

> ->E/Surface (25496): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xf46fec90

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          //Drawer Header
          //Drawer Body
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                drawerItem(context, () {
                  Get.to(() => ProfileScreen());
                }, "Hesabım", Icons.person),
                drawerItem(context, () {
                  Get.to(() => MyAdress());
                }, "Adreslerim", Icons.location_on_sharp),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  GestureDetector drawerItem(
      BuildContext context, VoidCallback onTap, String? a, IconData icon) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(icon, color: Colors.black54),
        title: Text(
          a.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should extract into `StatelessWidgets` instead of extracting widget as a function.

I have a working example of the drawer with navigation in Flutter GetX. You can take a look at this:

```js
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            DrawerItem(
              icon: Icons.abc,
              onTap: () => Get.to(const DemoView()),
              title: "Home",
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: const SizedBox.shrink(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the drawer item widget

```js
class DrawerItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final IconData icon;
  const DrawerItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.icon,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(icon, color: Colors.black54),
        title: Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: didn't work i have same problem

Comment: could you please share your pubspec.yaml file's getx dependency?

Comment: dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.17
  get: ^4.6.5
  flutter_slidable: ^2.0.0
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2: ^4.2.6
  http: ^0.13.5
  uuid: ^3.0.6
  google_maps_flutter: 2.2.3
  geolocator: ^8.2.1
  geocoding: ^2.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
  cloudinary_public: ^0.20.0
  google_maps_cluster_manager: ^3.0.0+1 
  fluster: ^1.2.0

Comment: I am having this problem in my 2 apps. I am having this problem in another button in other application